# How do I rearrange this equation to get the following?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rationalising-denominator

I have the following equation where $g = 9.8$
$$
T= \dfrac{25g}{1/2+\sqrt3/2}.
$$
I need to get:
$$
T = -25g + 25\sqrt3g ,
$$
but I keep ending up with this but with the signs reversed so
$$
T = 25g - 25\sqrt3g.
$$

Comment: What is $$\frac1{1+\sqrt3}?$$

Comment: Strategy for resolving such issues in the future: Note that your final expression is negative (since $\sqrt3 > 1$), so somewhere along the way, the sign has changed. Carefully check each expression in your derivation to determine where it changed, and that's where the mistake will be.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{1}{\frac 1 2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} } = \frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2(1-\sqrt 3)}{(1+\sqrt 3)(1-\sqrt 3)} = \frac{2-2\sqrt 3}{1-3} = \frac{2(1-\sqrt 3)}{-2}=-1 + \sqrt 3 \\
$$
Multiplying with $25g$ yields the wanted result

Comment: You're an angel 